# XML Deserialization to Class, Add to List

Tags: c#, serialization

I'm creating an application that has an import function, allowing the end-user to import XML config files.

The main application configuration XML file (CONFIG_FILE) itself consists of the following format:

```
<Config>
  <Facilities>
    <Facility>
      <Profiles>
        <Profile>
          <Name>Test</Name>
        </Profile>
      </Profiles>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <Name>Facility Name</Name>
    </Facility>
  </Facilities>
</Config>
```

Note: there can be multiple `<Facility>` nodes listed under `<Facilities>`. The  node is of the same nature; there can be multiple `<Profile>` nodes under the main `<Profiles>` parent. When a config file is imported, I want to take the `<Facility>` node (and its child items, like the respective  and  nodes, too) and place them in the main CONFIG_FILE.

User configuration files that can be imported have the following format:

```
<Facility xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Profiles>
    <Profile>
      <Name>Test</Name>
    </Profile>
  </Profiles>
  <ID>15</ID>
  <Name>Facility Name</Name>
</Facility>
```

The file to be imported is a compressed GZip File. Here is the code logic for the config file import. Basically it will deserialize the file chosen from the file dialog window.

```
var config = new Config();
if (File.Exists(CONFIG_FILE)) config = Serializer.DeserializeObjectFromFile<Config>(CONFIG_FILE);

Facility facilityBundle;

FileStream stream = new FileStream(openFileDialog.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
using (Stream stream2 = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
{
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Facility));
    facilityBundle = (Facility)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stream2);
}

config.Facilities.Add(new Facility { ID = facilityBundle.ID, Name = facilityBundle.Name });
Serializer.SerializeObjectToFile<Config>(config, CONFIG_FILE);
```

And here's the classes for serialization/deserialization:

```
[XmlRoot("Facility")]
public class Facility
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Profile> Profiles = new List<Profile>();
}

public class Profile
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Config
{
    public List<Facility> Facilities { get; set; }
}
```

The issue I'm having is when a config file is imported, it is completely ignoring the `<Profiles>` node and its child `<Profile>` node...so the main CONFIG_FILE essentially looks like this after import:

```
<Config>
  <Facilities>
    <Facility>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <Name>Facility Name</Name>
    </Facility>
  </Facilities>
</Config>
```

TL;DR basically, I need a way to deserialize an XML file's objects so they can be injected into another XML file for serialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add some annotation to your Profiles list property

```
[XmlArray("Profiles ")]
[XmlArrayItem("Profile", typeof(Profile))]
public List<Profile> Profiles = new List<Profile>();
```